# How to get id of a tr less than a number

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have following html table layout:

```
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12">
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="13">
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="15">
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="16">
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to insert a new tr by jquery. For this reason a id will be generated from the processing php page. Let the id is 11. So I have to insert it after the tr which id is less than 11. Here the tr is with the id 9. Problem is how can I find the closet tr which id is less than the generated id (here 11)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to find the `tr` elements with an `id` less than the required, then use `last()` to get the highest of them, and finally `after()` to add the HTML of the new table row. Try this:

```
var rank = 11; // calculate this as needed...
var newRow = '<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>';

$('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < rank;
}).last().after(newRow);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqst8kk1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is working but only after I add the filter function to any event. But I want to add new row after getting callback data from jquery post. Can you tell me, how can I find just the id of the tr in a var which is less than generated id (Here 9) (your final result is a added row, but I want just to get the id which is less than the generated id) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's probably best if you start a new question for that as it seems a broader topic than this question covers.

Comment: Please see my question that I just have posted in this topic.